# Open csv file via php

Tags: php, csv

I have problem with my csv parser. Sometimes in my CSV file I using syntax " as item name, for example:

1;73,09;41,66;23;89,9007
5907558600001;90;AAA-ACC;"Item descript 26""x32 ss";"etc";

As you can see, in my description in csv file have "" or " but it is not enclosure.

I try import this file to php using this code:

```
.....
            if (($handle = fopen($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], "r")) !== FALSE) {

                while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ";",'"')) !== FALSE) {

                    $de = 0;
                    $cat = str_replace(" ", "", $data[7]);
                    $ar1[$cat] = 'a';
                }
            }

            print_r($ar1);
....
```

Comment: You need to escape quotes

Comment: any way you can paste a couple more rows from your csv so I can verify things before posting? Also, try changing your fgetcsv to this and see if that works. `fgetcsv($handle, 0, ";"))`

Comment: Putting a quote after `AAA-ACC` would give you 3 valid fields (+ 1 empty at the end), but I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: fgetcsv($handle, 0, ";")) not works too, do you have any other idea ?

Comment: Your csv file is not valid. As you indicate yourself in the question, the fields are not properly quoted. In the example line, putting a `"` after `AAA-ACC` would fix it for that line (as an example).